# How to prevent an infinite recursion

Tags: javascript, jquery, algorithm, recursion

I am trying to recursively print out the contents of **jQuery**. I'm planning on using this to analyze an existing instance of jQuery (loaded in a page) against a small database of known "jQuery signatures", to determine what changes have been made (i.e. what plugins have been loaded, functions modified, etc.).

To do this, I have this small function:

```
function recurse(obj, iter){
    var padding = (new Array(iter + 1)).join("&nbsp;&nbsp;") + ">";

    for (var i in obj){
    document.writeln(padding + i + "<br/>");

    if (iter < 5)
        recurse(obj[i], iter + 1);
    }
}
```

When I execute this:

```
recurse(jQuery, 1);
```

I get something like this:

```
  >prototype
    >init
      >prototype
        >init
          >prototype
        >selector
        >jquery
          >0

.... On and on and on .....
```

My problem is, at the very beginning, you can see that `prototype` and then `init` repeat over and over again. The only reason it stopped at 5 deep is because of the `if (iter < 5)` check. If the limit wasn't there, it would have recurred [sic?] forever. The iteration limit helps, but what if there is a critical function 6 deep? Essentially, I have no idea what I should make this iteration limit, or if there should be one at all.

Instead, I'm thinking there must be some kind of algorithm that can prevent never-ending recursion. Does such an algorithm exist? Or should I change how I go about traversing jQuery? Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could keep track of what values you've already seen, and just bail out when you see one again.

```
function recurse(obj) {
  var marker = '__' + new Date().getTime() + '__';
  function r(obj, iter) {
    if (marker in obj) return;

    var padding = (new Array(iter + 1)).join("&nbsp;&nbsp;") + ">";
    obj[marker] = true;

    for (var i in obj) {
      if (!obj.hasOwnProperty(i) || i === marker) continue;

      document.writeln(padding + i + "<br/>");

      recurse(obj[i], iter + 1);
    }
  }
  r(obj, 0);      
}
```

Now this of course has the disadvantage of leaving your traversed object graph littered with extra properties, but for some applications that wouldn't be a problem. Also using the clock to make a "unique" marker is really lame; you might want to just use a counter, or maybe just a fixed nonsense string.

*edit* — Also, another issue (present in the original code too) is that this really should be checking to see if the "obj" values are really objects. If they're scalars, then there's no point doing anything, really. You'd just need to do a "typeof" check right after checking for the marker, and if you see null, a number, a string, or a boolean, just return.

Comment: Note that objects pass by reference and works with variables at higher scope than the called functions.

Comment: @user257493 huh? I'm not sure I understand what that has to do with anything. However you're right that numeric or boolean-valued properties would mess this up; I'll edit the function.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. I'll try this out later and tell you if it worked.

Comment: OK - it's not the prettiest thing in the world. Good luck!

Comment: I was able to adapt this algorithm. It works well, but locks the browser. I'll keep fine-tuning it and then hopefully I post something working. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Your recursion is missing a base case.  See the definition of [Recursion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion).  You introduced an arbitrary base case of `(depth < 5)`.  Maybe instead use the length of the array, or as Pointy pointed out, the hasOwnProperty check to skip the recursive call.

Answer (score 0):

Unless i am missing something, all you need to do is to skip strings (if you use a modern browser that allows indexing of strings, otherwise it doesn't matter) and the init function which is the jQuery self reference that gives you the infinite recursion

```
function recurse(obj, iter){
    var padding = (new Array(iter + 1)).join("&nbsp;&nbsp;") + ">";

    for (var i in obj){
        document.writeln(padding + i + "<br/>");
        if (i != 'init' && typeof obj[i] != 'string') 
            recurse(obj[i], iter + 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As several answers said: You algorithm must contain a proper break case to prevent infinite recursion.

But what happen if you cannot control the input of your algorithm?

For that case, or just for development purposes, you could use this:

```
function acmeRecursion(){
  var count = localStorage.getItem("count");
  if(count>50){
    throw new Error("recursion limit exceeded");
  }
  count++;

  //put your logic here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Building off of Pointy's answer (ideally this would be a comment, but alas, code doesn't work great in those), a better solution might be to just pass along an object to the the recurse function that will keep track of objects you've already seen.  Something like this:

```
var recurse = function(obj)
{
    var seen = {};
    var inner = function(obj, padding)
    {
        for (var i in obj)
        {
            if (!(obj[i] in seen))
            {
                document.writeln(padding + i + '<br />');
                seen[obj[i]] = true;
                inner(obj[i], padding + '  ');
            }
        }
    };
    return inner(obj, '');
};
```

Which uses a closure rather than an argument to pass along the `seen` object, for the sake of simplicity, but the basic concept is the same.

This approach has the advantage of not adding extra attributes to the objects you're traversing.

**Edit:** I meant to explain this, but forgot.  I'm not using [`hasOwnProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) here because in the case of printing an object graph, you probably *do* want to see inherited attributes.

Comment: the test `obj[i] in seen` won't work. It will try to find a property called `obj[i].toString()` in seen. You'd need some hashing code to key your objects by a unique id, which would be quite a rabbit hole.

Comment: Yes exactly - I started writing this version, in fact, until I realized exactly the problem @Juan Mendes has pointed out. That's what I resorted to the ugly hack of tracking markers on objects that have been "touched".

Comment: Hmm, my understanding is that Javascript objects have no problem using other objects as keys, and the code seems to work just fine.  Can you point me to an article or somesuch that describes the behavior you're talking about?  Maybe I'm misunderstanding you...

Comment: Haha, oh, right.  It merely appears to work because when printed using `document.writeln`, the object gets converted to a string anyway.